# Guardar en un array, objetos instanciados por una clase en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Quería preguntar si hay una forma de guardar en un array objetos instanciados a partir de una clase.
Esta es solo una parte del código, por eso no andaría.

```javascript
class Pregunta {
    constructor(pregunta, opciones, datoDelUsuario) {
        this.pregunta = pregunta;
        this.opciones = opciones;
        this.datoDelUsuario = datoDelUsuario;
    
    }
    function preguntasUCM() {
    
        let preguntaUCM1 = new Pregunta("Que raza es aliada de Loki en Avengers? Ingresá el numero correspondiente.",
            "\n1. Chitauri \n 2. Klyntar \n 3. Kronans \n 0. Para salir", datoUsuario)
        preguntaUCM1.mostrarPregunta()
        preguntaUCM1.contadorDePuntos()
    
        let preguntaUCM2 = new Pregunta("¿Por quien consigue Clint la gema del Alma? \n Ingresá el nro correspondiente.",
            "\n 1. Viuda Negra \n 2. Bruja Escarlata \n 3. Gamora \n 4. Carol Danvers \n 0. Para salir", datoUsuario)
        preguntaUCM2.mostrarPregunta()
        preguntaUCM2.contadorDePuntos()
    
        let preguntaUCM3 = new Pregunta("¿Que Avenger crea a Vision? \n Ingresá el nro correspondiente.",
            "\n 1. Iron Man \n 2. Thor \n 3. Bruja Escarlata \n 4. Clint \n 0. Para salir", datoUsuario)
        preguntaUCM3.mostrarPregunta()
        preguntaUCM3.contadorDePuntos()
    
        arrayPreguntas = [preguntaUCM1, preguntaUCM2, preguntaUCM3]
        preguntaUCM3.jugarDeNuevo()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si quieres usar un método como factoría para crear muchas instancias, no es

```
 function preguntasUCM() {...}
```

sino

```
 static preguntasUCM() {...}
```

se asume que son funciones. El prefijo `static` te permitiría generar tu array via  `Pregunta.preguntasUCM()` sin usar `new`.

Sin embargo con eso llegarás a tu `arrayPreguntas`, que es lo que motiva la pregunta. Eso es una variable libre. No estás guardándola en la clase.

Desde un método estático sólo podrías almacenarla como static member

```
Pregunta.arrayPreguntas = [...]
```

Pero eso afecta a la clase misma. O sea si llamas a `preguntasUCM()` dos veces pierdes la referencia al primero. Y no, no son el mismo objeto.

Por qué no refactorizar eso para que `preguntasUCM()` sea en sí una clase `PreguntasCollection` cuyo constructor no requiera parámetros, y tenga una propiedad *de instancia* que puedas asignar como `this.preguntasCollection = [...]` sin romper nada?

```
class Pregunta {
    constructor(pregunta, opciones, datoDelUsuario) {
        this.pregunta = pregunta;
        this.opciones = opciones;
        this.datoDelUsuario = datoDelUsuario;

    }
}

class PreguntasCollection {
    
    constructor() {
    
        let preguntaUCM1 = new Pregunta("Que raza es aliada de Loki en Avengers? Ingresá el numero correspondiente.",
            "\n1. Chitauri \n 2. Klyntar \n 3. Kronans \n 0. Para salir", datoUsuario)
        preguntaUCM1.mostrarPregunta()
        preguntaUCM1.contadorDePuntos()
    
        let preguntaUCM2 = new Pregunta("¿Por quien consigue Clint la gema del Alma? \n Ingresá el nro correspondiente.",
            "\n 1. Viuda Negra \n 2. Bruja Escarlata \n 3. Gamora \n 4. Carol Danvers \n 0. Para salir", datoUsuario)
        preguntaUCM2.mostrarPregunta()
        preguntaUCM2.contadorDePuntos()
    
        let preguntaUCM3 = new Pregunta("¿Que Avenger crea a Vision? \n Ingresá el nro correspondiente.",
            "\n 1. Iron Man \n 2. Thor \n 3. Bruja Escarlata \n 4. Clint \n 0. Para salir", datoUsuario)
        preguntaUCM3.mostrarPregunta()
        preguntaUCM3.contadorDePuntos()
    
        this.arrayPreguntas = [preguntaUCM1, preguntaUCM2, preguntaUCM3]
        preguntaUCM3.jugarDeNuevo()
    }
}
```

no aspiro a entender qué hacen los demás métodos, ni por qué es `preguntaUCM3` el encargado de jugarDeNuevo.

**Por qué es una mejor solución**

Quieres almacenar tres instancias en un array, y a su vez mantener la referencia a éste para usarlo en otro lado, me imagino. Desde el método estático sólo podrías guardar eso en una variable estática, pero al modificarla, como no es una variable de instancia, pisa cualquier valor de invocaciones anteriores.

Esto podrías evitarlo invocando al constructor con `new Pregunta` pero no es un poco raro que una instancia se contenga a sí misma?

Comment: Hola, como estas?
Agradezco tu respuesta, pero no termino de entender que es lo que mejoras haciendo la clase PreguntasCollection.
preguntaUCM3 es el encargado por que es la ultima pregunta